# Executing code automatically at program start without violating ODR

Tags: c++, c++17, one-definition-rule

I try to code a simple way to execute code at start of the program automatically (without using not portable attribute()).

I wrote the following code, and I'm asking if it does violate the ODR if the code written before main() is put in header files.
Or, does the inline function and variable prevent that?
Would there be a case where the function would be called twice if the ODR is violated?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//-----

template <void(*init_function)()>
class execute_at_start
{
    struct dummy final {};
    ~execute_at_start() = delete;
    inline static dummy execute_() { init_function(); return dummy{}; }
    inline static dummy auto_init_ = execute_();
};

//-----

inline void echo(){ std::cout << "echo" << std::endl; }

template class execute_at_start<&echo>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "EXIT SUCCESS" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: _the code written before main()_ means everything from the include to the explicit template instantiation. So the question is, does the explicit template instantiation cause ODR violation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be ODR-safe. The C++ standard requires that there is only one instance of static data member `auto_init_` for each distinct instantiation of `execute_at_start<>` class template and that it is initialized once.

Itanium C++ ABI (most compilers comply with it, apart from MSVC) requires guard variables for globals (`auto_init_` here) to make sure they are initialized once:

> If a function-scope static variable or a static data member with vague linkage (i.e., a **static data member of a class template**) is dynamically initialized, then there is an associated guard variable which is used to guarantee that construction occurs only once.

See [Itanium C++ ABI §2.8 Initialization Guard Variables](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#guards) for more details.

---

Another standard ODR-safe solution for this problem that doesn't rely on guard variables is [Schwarz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter). It has been used to initialize the standard streams (`std::cout` and friends) since the dawn of C++. In this solution `counter` is an explicit guard variable that has external linkage and it makes sure only the first invocation of `execute_at_start` constructor calls `init_function`:

```
// Header begin.
#include <iostream>

template<void(*init_function)()>
class execute_at_start {
    static inline int counter = 0;
public:
    execute_at_start() {
        if(!counter++)
            init_function();
    }
};

inline void echo() { std::cout << "echo" << std::endl; }

execute_at_start<echo> const execute_at_start_echo; // A copy in each translation unit.

// Header end.

int main() {}
```

Comment: `static` can be used instead of `const` here (I think it in fact implies `static` in this case).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I prefer just `const`. `const` implies `static` for objects at global and namespace scope.